# Get binary value of any file

Tags: java, binary

If suppose I have a file such as `music.mp3` or `image.jpg` or any file to be considered. How do i get the binary representation of those files to a string value in java so that i can view it ??

Eg: Suppose I have file called `'video.mp4'` then it must be represented as `101011010101000111010` or something like that in memory i need to get the value and store it in String like `String s = "101011010101000111010"`

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this in java ??

EDIT 2
How can i convert back the string to the actual file ??

Comment: First [read the file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250229/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-single-byte-array-in-java)

then [display the bytes, one by one, as binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263187/how-can-i-print-a-integer-in-binary-format-in-java)

Comment: You really want it in binary? Not in hexadecimal?

Comment: read here.. it's the same question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119141/java-file-to-binary-conversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest hexadecimal, it's much more compact and readable

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("1.txt"))) {
        for (int b; (b = is.read()) != -1;) {
            String s = Integer.toHexString(b).toUpperCase();
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(s).append(' ');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

output

```
71 77 65 77 65 72 0D 0A 71 77 72 65 0D 0A 72 77 65 72 0D 0A
```

for binary string change the code

```
            String s = "0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(b);
            s = s.substring(s.length() - 8); 
            sb.append(s).append(' ');
```

and get this output

```
01110001 01110111 01100101 01110111 01100101 01110010 00001101 00001010
```

and this is how to parse the string and write back to a file

```
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("2.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int b = sc.nextInt(2);
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
```

Comment: That's not the answer to Grish's question. He asked for binary output, why write hexadecimal version? I also think that it is much more readable, but the whole concept of stackoverflow (i think) is to answer questions as preceisely as possible.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev: How can i convert back the string to the actual file ??

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev: I used the `FileWriter` to create the file using `Scanner sc = new Scanner(sb.toString());` but i am getting a 0kb file ?? Can you explain how to write it ??

Comment: See my update. It parses "01110001 01110111 ..." and writes it byte by byte to 2.txt

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev How would I go about writing the hex values back to a file? Above you showed how to do it if we are putting the binary values to a new file, but how do we do it with hex?